# Cut shapes off a surface

Tags: modifiers

Is it possible to cut any shape on a nurbs surface? I tried to use boolean modifier in the image below but it appears an error... 
[image: I would like to remove the intersection of the]

Answer (score 2):

There are a bit of errors:

- The pot-like object has to be converted to a mesh. (**Alt+C** then *Select Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text*)
- The modifier should be applied to the pot-like object and the object in the modifier should be the parallelepiped (The one Selected in The Photo).
- The normals in the pot-like object are pointing in the wrong
  direcion, so you have to adjust them if you won't the modifier not
  to have a strange behavior.  to adjust the normal press **tab** to go
  into edit mode, then press **w** and select *Flip Normals*

Then The modifier Should Work.